# How does element-wise comparison of dicts, lists and tuples work in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, python-2.x

```
[1,3] > [1,2]
True
```

OK, sounds reasonable, on an intuitive level if nothing else.

```
(3,2) <= (3,2)
True
```

Ditto.

But what makes:

```
(4,3) >= (1,1,1)
True
```

And if we are comparing `values()` here:

```
{'a':1, 'b':2} < {'a':1, 'b':3}
True
```

Then why are we comparing `keys()` here:

```
{'a':1, 'b':2} < {'x':1, 'y':2}
True
```

I don't find documentation on these phenomena anywhere.

Comment: Dicts aren't sequences. Don't compare them. In Python 2, it'll sort-of work, producing mostly-consistent but meaningless results. In Python 3, it'll raise a TypeError.

Comment: Also, don't jump to conclusions. The dict comparison logic is not comparing `keys()` or `values()` in either of your examples.

Comment: @user2357112 I knew someone would call me out on my conclusion-jumping. Good. Now for an explanation of what **is** going on, if it's not keys and values that are being compared.

Comment: If you really want to know, [you can take a look under the hood](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/dictobject.c#l1792). The short answer is that the results are meaningless and producing a result at all was a design mistake.

Comment: and Python 3 has been all about fixing such mistakes (raising `TypeError` in this case).

Comment: @user2357112 Was not aware of that URL for the under-the-hood implementations. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(4,3)` is larger than `(1,1,1)` for the exact same reason that `"mouse"` is larger than `"elephant"`. [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). With strings you're probably very familiar with it. You'd expect "elephant" to appear before "mouse" in a dictionary, right?

Comment: Funny that, I posted a question recently along the lines of, 'Why is 123 < 'foo'?', and was promptly told, 'Because Guido said so'.

Comment: @Pyderman I guess I removed that while you were typing :-) (I didn't really have something to say about dicts)

Answer (score 4):

All this is very clearly documented in [Python Language Reference 5.9 Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Especially:

> - Tuples and lists are compared lexicographically using comparison of    corresponding elements. This means that to compare equal, each
>     element must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same
>     type and have the same length.
>        If not equal, the sequences are ordered the same as their first    differing elements. For example, `cmp([1,2,x], [1,2,y])` returns the
>     same as `cmp(x,y)`. If the corresponding element does not exist, the
>     shorter sequence is ordered first (for example, `[1,2]` < `[1,2,3]`).
> - Mappings (dictionaries) compare equal if and only if their sorted    `(key, value)` lists compare equal. [1] Outcomes other than equality
>     are resolved consistently, but are not otherwise defined. [2]

where the footnotes are

> 1. The implementation computes this efficiently, without constructing lists or sorting.
> 2. Earlier versions of Python used lexicographic comparison of the sorted (key, value) lists, but this was very expensive for the common
>      case of comparing for equality. An even earlier version of Python
>      compared dictionaries by identity only, but this caused surprises
>      because people expected to be able to test a dictionary for emptiness
>      by comparing it to `{}`.

---

Comparing dictionaries in Python 3 raises `TypeError`. Likewise sequences having incompatible elements:

```
>>> {} < {1:2}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()
>>> ['a'] < [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```